# x86 Assembly: int13h seems to not load program

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

Recently I've been trying to make an operating system for fun and I started with the bootloader. First I'd like to start by saying I asked another question about the same side effect (program not running) yesterday, but it turns out the cause is probably different than what I first thought. So, this is the bootloader code:

```
start: jmp boot

boot:
    cli                               ; Disable interrupts
    cld                               ; Clear direction flags


    mov al, 2                         ; Read 2 sectors
    mov ch, 0                         ; Track 0
    mov cl, 2                         ; Read 2nd sector (1st sector is bootloader)
    mov dh, 0                         ; Head number
    mov dl, 0                         ; Drive number (0 = floppy drive)

    ; Specify memory address to read floppy to
    mov cx, 0x5000
    mov bx, cx
    mov es, bx
    xor bx, bx

    mov ah, 0x2                       ; INT 0x13 with AH=0x2 means read sector
    int 0x13                          ; Call BIOS to read sector
    jmp cx                            ; Jump to sector

  ; Must be 512 bytes
  times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
  dw 0xAA55                           ; Boot Signature
```

However, the sample program I have never runs. Running this on QEMU, I previously thought the issue was that the `jmp` goes to the wrong address, but now after getting a memory dump and doing some more debugging I see that the `jmp` happens and it goes to the correct address, but address 0x5000 is all zeroes and has absolutely nothing, nor does anything near it. Could this be a problem with GDB/QEMU not being good with segmentation or real mode? I read something about that. Or perhaps I am using `int 0x13` wrong? Perhaps segmentation doesn't work like this? Since I use the value of a register for the address to start storing the data into and then also use it to jump there, shouldn't it be the exact same address thus should be correct? I couldn't find anything on the internet helping with this and I'm totally confused. Please enlighten me. All help is appreciated, thank you!

Steps taken to build disk image:

First, I build the bootloader with:

```
nasm -f elf bootloader.asm -F dwarf -g -o ../build/bootloader/bootloader.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T bootloader.lds ../build/bootloader/bootloader.o -o ../build/bootloader/bootloader.o.elf
objcopy -O binary  ../build/bootloader/bootloader.o.elf ../build/bootloader/bootloader.o
```

Linker script:

```
OUTPUT(bootloader);

PHDRS
{
  headers PT_NULL;
  text PT_LOAD FILEHDR PHDRS ;
  data PT_LOAD ;
}


SECTIONS
{
  . = SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .text 0x7c00:  {  *(.text)  } :text
  .data :  {  *(.data)  } :data
}
```

In order to create it with debug info to make using it with GDB easier.

Then, this is the sample program I use:

```
start: jmp MovCursor

MovCursor:
    cld
    mov ah, 0x2
    mov bh, 0
    mov dh, 12
    mov dl, 0
    int 0x10
    jmp PutChar

PutChar:
    mov ah, 0xA
    mov al, 0x49
    mov bh, 0
    mov cx, 1
    int 0x10
    hlt
    jmp Print

Print:
    mov si, msg          ; Load start address of the message into SI
    jmp printstring

printstring:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    lodsb                ; Load byte at DS into AL, increment SI
    or al, al            ; Check if AL is 0 (and set flags)
    jz exitloop          ; If zero jump to end
    mov ah, 0xE          ; INT 0x10/AH=0xE is teletype output
    int 0x10             ; Call BIOS to print
    jmp printstring      ; Repeat for next character

exitloop:
    hlt

msg db "Welcome to kOS!", 0ah, 0dh, 0h
```

Compiled as a raw binary with `nasm -f bin os/io.asm -o os/io`.

Then, finally, to build the image:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=build/bootloader/bootloader.o of=disk.img bs=512 seek=0
dd if=os/io of=disk.img bs=512 seek=1
```

QEMU command: `qemu-system-i386 -machine q35 -fda disk.img -gdb tcp::26000 -S`

Comment: `mov cx, 0x5000` overwrites your CH:CL = 0:2.  Set up ES first, and don't use 2 different regs ; `mov bx,cx` seems completely pointless vs. `xor bx,bx` / `mov ax, 0x5000` / `mov es, ax`.  Check register values with a debugger right before `int 0x13` runs, to make sure all of CL, CH, AL, AH and so on hold the args you want.

Comment: Also IIRC, DL on entry to the bootloader hold the drive number you were booted from, so use that instead of forcing floppy.

Comment: You are trying to read the sector to `ES:BX`, which is `0x5000:0x5000h`, but the near `jmp cx`  jumps to `CS:CX` which probably is `0x4C00:0x0002`.  You need to use far jump to `0x5000:0x5000` instead. Also you might want to check `CF` and `AX` returned from http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm

Comment: @PeterCordes I changed the instructions and made sure that the registers were all set correctly (had to do some manual changing with GDB but I'll look into this later), I still don't see a program loaded

Comment: @vitsoft I checked the memory address that should be calculated with that segmented address (0x73000, right?), in fact, I checked the entire memory dump and couldn't find the hex bytes of my program loaded. I also checked CF and AX, CF isn't set so that's fine, and AX is 0x2 (probably from AL and AH also being 2).

Comment: With `xor bx, bx` the destination address is `0x5000:0x0000`, linear address `0x50000`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I checked that, too. There's nothing loaded

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how you built the program and the disk image.  It's possible that the sector is being loaded correctly but doesn't contain what you intended it to.

Comment: I used nasm to output a raw binary of the program, and then I used dd to load that binary to a .img file right after the bootloader, then I use that image as a floppy disk in QEMU and let the bootloader do what it has to do.

Comment: @KosmasRaptis Are you sure that the 2nd and 3rd sectors of your virtual floppy aren't all-zero? Can you monitor the memory at `ES:BX` before and after `INT 0x13`.

Comment: Please copy and paste into your question the exact commands you're running to build and boot your disk image, start to finish.  I tried sticking a few extra instructions following your `dw 0xAA55`, which would go in the next sector, and fixing your `cx` overwrite bug and adding `jmp 0x5000:0000`.  I tested with Bochs and the sector is loaded and jumped to correctly.  So I think something's wrong with your build process, but your description is not precise enough to identify what it is.

Comment: @NateEldredge I updated the answer with the commands, thank you for putting in effort to help me with this.

Comment: @vitsoft Most of sector 2 and 3 are zeros, however memory before and after in the expected locations is all zeros

Comment: `nasm -f elf` assembles 32-bit code by default.  Unless there is a `BITS 16` at the top of your `bootloader.asm` that you haven't shown us, you're producing the wrong instructions for 16-bit real mode.  The idea of using the ELF toolchain for your boot sector is rather silly in the first place; just do `nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin` and skip the `ld` and `objcopy` lines.  (And please use `.bin` or `.img` for a raw binary image, not `.o` which is for relocatable object files.)

Comment: When you were single-stepping the boot sector with your debugger, didn't you notice that the instructions looked screwy and weren't what you intended (like `mov ebx,0xc38e5000`)?  Or is your debugger set in 32-bit mode as well?  gdb has a habit of doing that since that's what it was designed for; another reason why qemu+gdb is an inferior choice for real-mode development.

Comment: @NateEldredge I actually did observe that weird thing happening, and I have GDB set in i8086 architecture so I believe it is 16-bit mode. Also, I'll use binary now, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assembling your `bootloader.asm` with `nasm -f elf` which by default causes it to assemble 32-bit code.  Thus you get machine code that doesn't do the right thing when run in 16-bit real mode.

You may be able to work around by putting `bits 16` at the top of your `bootloader.asm` file.  But the ELF object file format isn't designed for 16-bit code in the first place, and trying to use it for such a small piece of code is rather absurd.  I would instead suggest just building the boot sector with

```
nasm -f bin -o bootloader.bin bootloader.asm
```

since `-f bin` uses 16-bit mode by default.  Then skip the `ld` and `objcopy` lines, and use `bootloader.bin` in place of what you previously called `bootloader.o` (which is not a good filename, since `.o` normally means a relocatable object file, not a binary image).

You won't have debug info, but that's sort of unnecessary anyway for code as short as a boot sector.  Just have your debugger disassemble the instructions as you step through them, and compare with your source code.

After fixing this and the bugs mentioned in comments (overwriting the track and sector numbers in `cx`, and needing to `jmp 0x5000:0000`) the code successfully boots, loads, and runs the sector.  It displays `I` on the screen and halts, just like you told it to.

Comment: It's not crazy to assemble 16-bit machine code into an ELF object file if you want debug metadata; that's normal for people using GAS and objcopy or a linker script for osdev stuff.  It does mean you need `bits 16` (or `.code 16` for GAS).  Agreed it's total overkill and over-complication for NASM, since unlike GAS, NASM can just output a flat binary in the first place, but it's not inherently wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Okay.  I was worried about whether ELF relocations work for 16-bit code, but after a little digging I see they do exist.

Comment: Oh right, yeah, valid concern but it does work.  Not that this code needs any (internal relative branches resolved at assemble time, not link time); that's why it works even without an `org 0x7c00` or `org 0` directive.  All that said, `nasm -f bin` is the right tool for the job here.  And disassembly is preferable for debugging anyway, not source-level; that's how you notice if something weird happened and you didn't get the instructions you thought you were going to.

Comment: Again, thanks a ton for helping me out with this!